# JavaFX fxml load exception (XMLStreamException)

Tags: java, javafx, xml-parsing, fxml

The fxml loads without problems on Linux and Windows 10, but there seems to be a problem with that on Windows 7.

> javafx.fxml.LoadException
>
> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.

The fxml is perfectly valid, as the program works fine on most PC's.

Comment: Are you using the same JDK version on both?

Comment: @James_D , all the computers use the latest Java version;

Comment: Pretty much impossible to tell without quite a lot more information. My best guess would be that the Windows 7 machine somehow has a different character encoding than that used to create the FXML file. Maybe try setting the `Charset` explicitly on the `FXMLLoader`. But again, there's really not enough information in the question to  do anything here but guess.